# How do you get a reference to $wpdb in a PHP script

Tags: php, wpdb

I am using a jQuery tokenizing autocomplete text entry (http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput) in a Wordpress form. This type of input calls a PHP script on the server (not a function) to build a list of choices from which the user may choose after the user has entered some text in the input box (very similar to your Tags input in this page). My script is located in a plugin directory on my site.
I declared

```
global $wpdb
```

but am getting a null result when I try an use its methods (like $wpdb->prefix). Clearly, Wordpress is not loaded for my PHP script. I tried adding

```
include('http://where2bwho2c.dev/wp-config.php');
include('http://where2bwho2c.dev/wp-load.php');
include('http://where2bwho2c.dev/wp-includes/wp-db.php');
```

to my script, but this had no effect. What do I need to do to make sure Wordpress is loaded in my PHP script so I can use $wpdb?

I looked at a previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42288109/wpdb-is-null-despite-being-global) but it was not clear what exactly I should do in this case where my script is not a function.

Answer (score -2):

I used

```
define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
```

it seems to work fine.

Comment: you should never interact with wordpress functions by loading the stack by yourself if you are doing a front end functionality. The only time it might be ok to do it is when an external application on the same server needs to interact with wordpress. Us the wordpress AJAX end point, or better use the json routes for AJAX type of functionality

Comment: ... part of the reason is that there is no defintive location for those files you include, and even if it is your own server it is better not to assume them if you do not have to.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I was just using these scripts to move some custom post data over to some custom database tables. I had loaded a bunch of content into custom post types in Wordpress before I realized the Wordpress database design just would not scale for what I had in mind, so I redesigned the site using some custom database tables, but I didn't want to lose my valid data, so I wrote scripts to port it over to the new tables (learned a lot about the internals of the Wordpress database). Anyway, the scripts are not part of the site, just utilities that I used on my development server.

Comment: that is a fair usage for what you describe in the answer, but it realy do not match the question ;)